# Sub-query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my schema:

```
    Table "Questoes";
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_quest | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | questao  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | nivel    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | tipo     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

    Table "Respostas";

    +----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id       | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | id_quest | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | resposta | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | r_valido | enum('0','1') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My query is:

```
SELECT q.questao, r.resposta 
FROM questoes q, respostas r 
WHERE q.id_quest IN (19,20,21) 
    AND q.id_quest=r.id_quest 
    AND r.r_valido = ( SELECT resposta FROM respostas WHERE r_valido= 1 )
```

What I need is the field `questao` from table `Questoes` and the field `resposta` from table `respostas` where field `r_valido = 1`.
The field `resposta` have 4 results, and only one is valid, in other words, where the field `r_valido = 1`.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset as a SQL Fiddle, with expected results?

Comment: Are those large tables? and maybe you can translate these tables / column names to english, i can't understand spanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT q.questao, r.resposta FROM questoes AS q JOIN respostas AS r ON r.id_quest = q.id_quest WHERE q.id_quest IN (19,20,21)  AND r.r_valido = "1"
```

Also I found out what is causing that weird error when you use `1` instead of `"1"` in the query:

> We strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration
>   values, because it does not save on storage over the appropriate
>   TINYINT or SMALLINT type, and it is easy to mix up the strings and the
>   underlying number values (which might not be the same) if you quote
>   the ENUM values incorrectly

Comment: The problem continue... doesn't return the correct values... the  query return the values where "r_valido" = 0

Comment: Try it now - with " arround the number 1, I tried the similar thing on localhost and it seems to help

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood you completely but i think this is what you looking for:

```
SELECT q.questao, r.resposta
FROM questoes as q
INNER JOIN respostas as r
    ON q.id_quest=r.id_quest 
WHERE
    q.id_quest IN (19,20,21) AND
    r.r_valido = '1'
```

Comment: I have 4 results(answers) for field "resposta" and the correct answer is when the field "r_valido" is equal to 1. Your query return the values where the field "r_valido" is equal to 0.